# How to temporarily house arbitrary dom nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, knockout.js

I'm doing a bit of advanced work in KnockoutJS, whereby I generate some html outside of the KO process, apply bindings to them, and then insert them in my page.

The problem is housing the new html.  My html is a couple of table rows, and when I do

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = template(viewModel);
```

the div strips out all the table content (my `tr` and `td` tags), presumably since divs can't contain table rows.

My cheesy workaround for the moment is below: use a tbody.  But I'd like something a bit more generalized.  I thought to use a document fragment, but that doesn't seem to have an innerHTML property to set.

What's the preferred way to handle this?

```
var div = document.createElement('tbody');
div.innerHTML = template(viewModel);
ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, div);

$(element).after($(div).contents());
```

Comment: As a workaround you could fetch the type of the parent node, create an empty detached new node of that type to house your contents and later fetch the items from there. But it'd be better to figure out why your contents are stripped to begin with.

Comment: @Nit - that's actually not a bad idea.  Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Looks like it depends on how you set the html [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/B7Kge/)

Comment: Silly question1: since you add table rows, why do you create a div instead of a table?? Silly question2: if you want to create a div, why do you create table rows instead of creating divs?

Comment: @GôTô - I want to create arbitrary content that could be anything.  It happens to be table rows this time.  I want to quickly create the content, and then append it to the dom.  Frankly I think Nit's comment may be the best answer.

Comment: @AdamRackis Ok, but by the time you create the elements I guess you know what kind of elements you are creating, no?

Comment: @GôTô - well, yeah, I could use jquery, or childNodes[0] or something to take a peek at what's in there, and adjust manually, but I'm ideally looking for a *general* solution that's as simple as possible.

Comment: `var templ = template(viewModel);var newElement = document.createElement($(templ).is("tr, tbody, thead") ? 'table' : 'div'); newElement.innerHTML(templ);` ? :)

Comment: See my answer for a more built in way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you could fetch the type of the parent node, create an empty detached new node of that type to house your contents, and later fetch the items from there.

It might look something like this, assuming you don't mind inserting the content *before* `element`, rather than after it:

```
var container = document.createElement(element.parentNode.tagName),
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

container.innerHTML = template(viewModel);
ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, container);
while (container.childNodes.length){
    frag.appendChild(container.childNodes[0]);
}
element.parentNode.insertBefore(frag, element);
```

But it'd be better to figure out why your contents are stripped to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will get this problem only with table parts.

Hence you can do this:

```
var templ = template(viewModel);
var newElement = document.createElement(
                     $(templ).is("tr, tbody, thead") ? 'table' : 'div'
                 ); 
newElement.innerHTML(templ);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nit's answer works but its still a bit of a hack, I would use a custom template source instead.

First you need to create a engine that uses strings as source, like

```
var stringTemplateSource = function (template) {
        this.template = template;
};

stringTemplateSource.prototype.text = function () {
    return this.template;
};

var stringTemplateEngine = new ko.nativeTemplateEngine();
stringTemplateEngine.makeTemplateSource = function (template) {
    return new stringTemplateSource(template);
};
```

Then you can use it from a custom binding like

```
ko.renderTemplate(template, bindingContext.createChildContext(data), { templateEngine: stringTemplateEngine }, element, "replaceChildren");
```

Were `template` is a string containing the actual html

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Good stuff, for sure, but my whole point here is, for performance intensive things, to cut out knockout completely.  And yeah, the whole thing is a hack, but it's extremely fast.

Comment: "apply bindings to them" You still apply bindings to them?  Wont get around KO there?