# Apply knockout bindings to template and get result as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an HTML template:

```
<script id="my-template" type="text/template">
  <div data-bind="text: value"></div>
</script>
```

I would like to bind this to a model and get the result as a string.

So binding to `{ "value": "Some text" }` should result in `"<div data-bind="text: value">Some text</div>"`. The reason I need it as a String is to pass it as an argument to [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/).

Seems like it should be possible with either `ko.renderTemplate` or `ko.applyBindings`, but renderTemplate is giving me a memoized function and applyBindings modifies the template in the DOM, which I don't want.

I also tried cloning the template and binding to the clone, but the cloned DOM node didn't seem to have the bindings applied. [JSFiddle of this attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/qpolarbear/achkn74d/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ko.renderTemplate` accepts an `afterRender` callback that might be of use. Taken from this [tutorial about rendering templates for Bootstrap modals](http://aboutcode.net/2012/11/15/twitter-bootstrap-modals-and-knockoutjs.html):

```
ko.renderTemplate(
  "mytemplate",
  viewModel,
  {
    afterRender: function(nodes) {
      console.log("rendered!");
    }
  },
  target
);
```

Here is a quick and dirty example that displays the rendered result as a string:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.templateToString = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

    ko.renderTemplate(
      "my-template",
      viewModel, {
        afterRender: function() {
          document.getElementById('result').innerText = element.innerHTML;
          element.innerHTML = null;
        }
      },
      element
    );

  }
};

ko.applyBindings({
  'value': 'Some text'
});
```

```css
pre {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<pre id="result"></pre>

<script id="my-template" type="text/template">
  <div data-bind="text: value"></div>
</script>

<div data-bind="templateToString"></div>
```

If you wish to use `renderTemplate` without touching the DOM or outside of a binding, create a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) instead:

```
var fragment       = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    container      = document.createElement('div'),
    bindingContext = ko.contextFor(document.body);

fragment.appendChild(container);

ko.renderTemplate(
  "my-template",
  viewModel, {
    afterRender: function() {
      console.log(container.innerHTML);
    }
  },
  container
);
```

Please note that this is likely very un-idiomatic Knockout code, and I would recommend the usage within the binding.

Comment: This sort of works, except I'm not sure what to put for target. I don't want it to update anything in the DOM. I only want the rendered String.

I tried `ko.renderTemplate('my-template', { 'value': 'Some text' }, { afterRender: function (result) { console.log(result); }}, $('<div>'), 'replaceNode')();` but it does not get rendered.

If I replace `$('<div>')` with `$('body')` then it does, but updates my DOM.

Comment: In Knockout, everything related to rendering belongs into bindings, so you'll need a DOM node anyway. Also, `ko.renderTemplate` doesn't work with detached jQuery objects. Where is the harm in using the binding? It's cleaned by `element.innerHTML = null` directly afterwards.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be able to use a [custom template source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24054094/100342), if above solution really isn't to your liking.

Comment: @Manan third option: I've added a way to use renderTemplate outside of bindings, by creating a `DocumentFragment` and grabbing a bindingContext with `ko.contextFor`.

Comment: Thanks! The document fragment is what I needed. I don't have anything against using the binding, it is just that I don't have anything in the DOM to bind it to. Like I mentioned I need the string to pass it to Bootstrap Tour, which will eventually use it to render some DOM elements, but at the time of binding they don't exist yet.